# How do I ensure consumers of my web applications pages have the latest script files after updates are pushed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Whenever I push updates for a .Net Core web application running on a Windows Server, users don't get the latest javascript and CSS files because the browser is using a cached version and some functionality is not pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a version number to the **css** url when you load it in the **html** file. When you update your **css**, update the version in your **html** aswell. This will let the browser think that its loading a new file and therefore it reloads the file you updated.

Add the version number like in the following snippet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css?v=1">
```